# Identify this novel about a female space mercenary/pilot

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, elizabeth-moon

I am looking for this novel as I quite enjoyed the excerpt I read. Opens with a woman traveling from one planet to another; other passengers include a wealthy, somewhat imperious old lady and her entourage. Something is "not right" with the ship, our heroine discovers that the captain is smuggling something, ends up taking over the ship. Once at their destination, the heroine becomes a guest of imperious old lady; some sort of equestrian game/hunt is taking place, turns out our heroine is quite good. Would like to find original story and any sequels if they exist. Reminded me a lot of Bujold and Ilisidi from "Foreigner" et al.

I believe I read this on Baen's web site in electronic format, I've been looking through the authors there but nothing rings a bell. This would have been in the past five years or so.

Answer (score 25):

I'm pretty sure that's *[Hunting Party](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunting_Party_(novel))* by Elizabeth Moon, the first book in her *[Familias Regnant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familias_Regnant)* series.

Comment: @MaryB If this is the correct answer please do not forget to Accept it.